# hide/show div after page load and based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm hiding/showing a div based on a selected checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="other" name="os[other]" value="6" onclick="toggle_form_element('os[other]')">
```

Here is my Javascript Function:

```
function toggle_form_element(id) {
    if ((document.getElementsByName(id)[0].checked)) {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sometimesHidden').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

At the moment this works fine. But if I'm submitting these values and saving them to a session. These Session is used to set the checkbox to `checked="checked"` like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="other" name="os[other]" value="6" onclick="toggle_form_element('os[other]')" <?PHP if(!empty($_SESSION['register']['os']['other'])) echo "checked=\"checked\""; ?>>
```

So if I'm reloading the page, the checkbox is already checked because of the available `$_SESSION` var. But the hidden div isn't visible. So how can I extend my JS Function that it is not only working "onclick". What should i use to check it always?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the status of this checkbox on page load

```
<body onload="toggle_form_element(id);">
```

Or if you're using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // This code executes when the page loads
  toggle_form_element(id);
});
```

Comment: @Blade0rz: So I have to use the onclick function in the checkbox for toggling when checking/unchecking and your solution for toggling if the page is loaded? (Both solutions at the same time)

Comment: @emjay Correct, so you need to toggle it both on page load and when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call toggle_form_element also when page is loaded, so use  and in your init function call toggle_form_element:

```
function init() {
  toggle_form_element("other");
}
```